# Can't set up IMAP on a working email server

Tags: dns, postfix, mail-server, smtp, imap

I've been trying to set up my local mail server using [this tutorial](http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsa-proof-your-e-mail-in-2-hours/) on my domain `Mydomain.me`.

I got to the point where I can successfully receive mail send to my address but I can't set up an IMAP account with thunderbird (cf Snapshot).

Weirdly enough, Thunderbird doesn't detect my IMAPS service. I tested it with `openssl s_client -connect mydomain.me:993` which seem to work fine. Of course when I try to set up encryption-free imap, I run into trouble.
[image: Setting up Thunderbird]

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ? My first guess are DNS records, and my second my postfix conf. I forgot to mention I'm trying to set up the account on another machine which is not necessarily on the same network.

Content of `cat main.cf | egrep -v "^#"` :

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.me
myorigin = $mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost 
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Content of `tail -n 30 /var/log/mail.log` :

```
Nov 28 16:55:07 myServerName postfix/anvil[5449]: statistics: max connection rate 7/60s for (smtp:192.168.0.254) at Nov 28 16:51:27
Nov 28 16:55:07 myServerName postfix/anvil[5449]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:192.168.0.254) at Nov 28 16:51:14
Nov 28 16:55:07 myServerName postfix/anvil[5449]: statistics: max cache size 2 at Nov 28 16:51:47
Nov 28 16:57:01 myServerName postfix/smtpd[6006]: connect from unknown[192.168.0.254]
Nov 28 16:57:01 myServerName postfix/smtpd[6006]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.0.254]
Nov 28 16:57:01 myServerName postfix/smtpd[6006]: connect from unknown[192.168.0.254]
Nov 28 16:57:01 myServerName postfix/smtpd[6006]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[192.168.0.254]: QUIT\r\n
Nov 28 16:57:01 myServerName postfix/smtpd[6006]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.0.254]
```

Here are my DNS records :

```
$TTL 3600
@   IN SOA dns106.ovh.net. tech.ovh.net. (2013112701 86400 3600 3600000 300)
              IN NS     dns106.ovh.net.
              IN NS     ns106.ovh.net.
              IN MX 1   mydomain.me.
              IN A      xx.xxx.x.xxx
              IN TXT    "1|www.mydomain.me"
ftp           IN CNAME  mydomain.me.
mail          IN CNAME  ns0.ovh.net.
ox            IN CNAME  ox.ovh.net.
pop3          IN CNAME  ns0.ovh.net.
smtp          IN CNAME  ns0.ovh.net.
www           IN MX 1   mydomain.me.
www           IN A      xx.xxx.x.xxx
www           IN TXT    "3|welcome"
www           IN TXT    "l|fr"
```

Comment: Did you reset Thunderbird to access IMAP on port 993 rather than the default 143? And the instructions say explicitly that your IMAP connection is being routed with SSL, which may also require changing the settings to use TLS/SSL auths when connecting to your Dovecot IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I solved it, and I still haven't laid out my solution, so here it is :

Although Thunderbird would not auto-detect anything, I just had to manually configure all the fields (ports for IMAP and SMTP, authentification methods, whose translation should be 'plain/unencrypted password') and everything would just work as expected.